# Can you split image input into two folders?

Tags: windows-10, script, shared-folders, folder-redirection

I have a question. If i take continuous photos with a camera (connected to the PC with a USB so the image saving is quick.) can i make it so for example image000 is saved automatically to "example folder 1" and the image001 is saved to "example folder 2" ? So the even numbers (0,2,4,6,8,10,12......) go into one folder and the odd numbers into the other . Do i need a script for that? if so how can i do this? I am using windows 10. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using either a batch file or power shell script. A simple batch file can be created like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
:START
for %%F in (*0.jpg *2.jpg *4.jpg *6.jpg *8.jpg) do move "%%F" "Folder1\"
for %%F in (*1.jpg *3.jpg *5.jpg *7.jpg *9.jpg) do move "%%F" "Folder2\"
Timeout /T 30
GOTO START
```

This file will keep looking for files after every 30 seconds and move files to different folders when file is found. 
Only negative point is, it will keep running in an infinite look. You need to stop it using `Ctrl + C` when you are done.

**Update:**

For automatic startup, you can create a shortcut in Startup folder of Start Menu with path to batch file and specifying working folder as path to image folder. Keep Run property of shortcut as Minimized. It will run and minimize to task bar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. That's exactly what I need. One more addition to that if you may. Is there a way to make the .bat script file run as soon as the user logs in? and can we make it so that it is not popped in front of the user just in case he accidentally closes the script? Again thank you very much

Comment: For automatic startup, you can create a shortcut in `Startup` folder of Start Menu with path to batch file and specifying working folder as path to image folder. Keep `Run` property of shortcut as `Minimized`. It will run and minimize to task bar.